# Most correct way for bit checking in C

Tags: c, gcc, linux-kernel, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I reading a book "Linux Kernel. Development. Third Edition." by Robert Love.

And in `softirq` section it's comment next piece of code:

```
    u32 pending;
    pending = local_softirq_pending();

    if (pending) {
            struct softirq_action *h;
            /* reset the pending bitmask */
            set_softirq_pending(0);
            h = softirq_vec;
            do {
                    if (pending & 1) /* STEP 4 */
                            h->action(h);
                    h++;
                    pending >>= 1;
            } while (pending);
    }
```

He discribe step by step what happens and most unclear step for me is 4:

> 4. If the first bit in pending is set, h->action(h) is called

I have following code to check if bit set like in book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BIT_SET(n) ((1) << (n))
#define BIT_CLEAR(n) ~((1) << (n))

int main(void)
{
        unsigned char bits = 0x0;

        bits |= BIT_SET(1);

        if (bits & (1 << 1))
                printf("TEST CHECK SET 1\n");

        if (bits & 1)
                printf("TEST CHECK SET 2\n");

        bits &= BIT_CLEAR(1);

        if (!(bits >> 1) & 1UL)
                printf("BITS UNSET\n");

        return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
gcc main.c -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror.
```

I always check if bit set with this one:

```
if (bits & (1 << n))
```

And my code make output like this:

```
TEST CHECK SET 1
BITS UNSET
```

Why `if (bits & 1)` statment is not work?:

So from several option which should I use and what exactly last one check?

```
if (bit & (1 << n))

if ((bit >> n) & 1)

if (bit & n)
```

Comment: `1 << 0` is `1`, therefore `bit & (1 << 0)` is the same as `bit & 1`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thx for answer, I rewrite my question to fit in MCV (i think so).

Comment: I think you should learn what _exactly_ the operators `&`, `<<` and `>>` do. Then you'll _actually_ understand what's going on.

Comment: Side note: your code has UB when you would try to set bit 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I always check if bit set with this one: `if (bits & (1 << n))`

This checks `n`-th bit in place; the code from the book, however, shifts the bit into the least-significant-bit position prior to making the check with `bits & 1`. In other words, by the time the code reaches the `if (bits & 1)` the value of `bits` has already been shifted such that the bit of interest is in 1-s position.

This is similar to your other check

```
if ((bit >> n) & 1)
```

except `(bit >> n)` part is done by performing `bit >>= 1` operation `n` times in a loop.

Note that in order for this code to work correctly `bit` must be unsigned.

> So from several option which should I use and what exactly last one check?

You misinterpreted the last check: it's not checking bit `n`, it's checking `bit` against the entire bit pattern of `n`'s binary representation.